# Inserting missing MultiIndex dates into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having dataframe with MultiIndex ['NmId', 'DateUtc'],

```
                    SaleQty  SaleAmount  OrderQty  OrderAmount
NmId    DateUtc                                               
6470000 2022-10-12        0        0.00         1       724.52
        2022-10-16        1      724.52         0         0.00
6470001 2023-06-18        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2023-06-19        0        0.00         0         0.00
```

I want to fill in the gaps between two dates from the first NmId element (6470000). So it would be:

```
                    SaleQty  SaleAmount  OrderQty  OrderAmount
NmId    DateUtc                                               
6470000 2022-10-12        0        0.00         1       724.52
        2022-10-13        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-14        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-15        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-16        1      724.52         0         0.00
6470001 2023-06-18        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2023-06-19        0        0.00         0         0.00
```

I tried different methods, for example, most obvious one with carthesian product:

```py
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
new_df = df.reindex(new_index)
```

But it results with all possible pairs of the indices, which I don't need:

```
                    SaleQty  SaleAmount  OrderQty  OrderAmount
NmId    DateUtc                                               
6470000 2022-10-12        0        0.00         1       724.52
        2022-10-13        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-14        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-15        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-16        1      724.52         0         0.00
        2023-06-18        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2023-06-19        0        0.00         0         0.00
6470001 2022-10-12        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-13        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-14        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-15        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2022-10-16        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2023-06-18        0        0.00         0         0.00
        2023-06-19        0        0.00         0         0.00
```

Any help appreciated

Dict values:

```
{'SaleQty': {(6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00')): 0,
  (6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-21 00:00:00')): 1,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-18 00:00:00')): 0,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00')): 0},
 'SaleAmount': {(6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00')): 0.0,
  (6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-21 00:00:00')): 724.52,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-18 00:00:00')): 0.0,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00')): 0.0},
 'OrderQty': {(6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00')): 1,
  (6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-21 00:00:00')): 0,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-18 00:00:00')): 0,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00')): 0},
 'OrderAmount': {(6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-12 00:00:00')): 724.52,
  (6472924, Timestamp('2022-10-21 00:00:00')): 0.0,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-18 00:00:00')): 0.0,
  (6637841, Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00')): 0.0}}
```

Comment: kindly provide the input data as a dictionary

Comment: @sammywemmy edited

Comment: Use `df.reset_index('NmId').groupby('NmId').apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D')).drop('NmId', axis=1).fillna(0)`

Comment: @jezrael, thanks, that helped